# Horizontally align DIVs with children of absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

CSS Experts! first, huge apology if this seems to be a duplicate!

I have a group of buttons with text that I'd like to arrange horizontally. For that reason I use a `div` with `display: "flex"` to enclose them as its children. Each button has a base layout as follows:

```
<div>
    <div style={normalStyle}>
        <div style={lineStyle}/>
        <div style={circleStyle}>
            <div style={onButtonStyle}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    {children}
</div>
```

where a minimized version of styles that I use are as follows:

```
{
    normalStyle: {
        position: "relative",
        cursor: "pointer",
    },

    lineStyle: {
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: "10px",
        height: "15px",
        width: "38px",
    },

    circleStyle: {
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 7,
        height: "20px",
        width: "20px",
    },

    onButtonStyle: {
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        height: "20px",
        width: "20px",
    }
}
```

The goal is to implement some sort of a material button where I have a slider (with `lineStyle`) and a base circle (with `circleStyle`) and an overlay button circle (with `onButtonStyle`) which expands or shrinks depending upon the checked status of the button (`transition` styles aren't shown here for sake of simplicity).

It appears that the text (`children`) isn't respecting the button and as a result they overlap, which I suspect it has something to do with the `absolute` positioning. Moreover, when I want to place multiple of these buttons horizontally, they look something like this:

[image]

The texts are apparently aligned horizontally (as expected) but the buttons are again positioned in an `absolute` manner w.r.t. the child text.

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
   <Button>A toggle button</Button>
   <Button>A toggle button</Button>
```

I searched around and frankly got numerous solutions but so far I badly failed to get this working. Really appreciate if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MrLister Terribly sorry but can you a bit elaborate what you're referring to? Do you mean what if I enclose the text in quotes? If that's the question, no difference. Happy to answer in a better way if I understand the question :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure I understood you question..
I took you code and cleaned it + turned into simple HTML and CSS for clarity.

First thing `.toggleStyle` needs an explicit size give that the children are all absolute positioned the parent is technically invisible. This is the reason the text is overlapping ur div.
I used flexbox to make the elements sit next to each others. You can look at using fixed width divs and floats if you prefer.

Last thing, you `onButtonStyle` shouldn't be absolute positioned because doing that it will be absolute to the first relative parents it finds in the nesting and won't sit inside it's parent.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggleStyle">
    <div class="lineStyle"></div>
    <div class="circleStyle">
      <div class="onButtonStyle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  this is where you will add you {children}  -->
  <label class="textStyle">Button Text</label>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
.toggleStyle {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}

.lineStyle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.circleStyle {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.onButtonStyle {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.textStyle {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I made this [Pen](https://codepen.io/fabioioio/pen/vWxvEv) for you.

I hope it is clear!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If you add `<div class="onButtonStyle" />` inside `<div class="circleStyle"></div>` you can easily reproduce my issue. Your example works because you don't have any `div` with class `onButtonStyle` in it. Also remember that I need the `div` with `onButtonStyle` to be inside `div` with `circleStyle` otherwise it won't move with the circle when I do transition for `left`.

Comment: I just added that div, is this what you need?

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm!

Comment: @FabioVella Just dumping code is not considered a good answer. For other users to understand how and why this answer work, an explanation is necessary. Let me know when you updated with that and I'll reconsider my down vote.

Comment: @LGSon sure I'll explain :)

Comment: Well, since there is a `container` element, you need to more clear with which _container_ needs an explicit size, also being the reason the text is overlapping, as if you mean the `container`, then it is wrong. And that the `onButtonStyle` shouldn't be absolute positioned is inaccurate, it work just fine being absolute positioned. Still, I retracted my down vote.